# NullPointerException in java code.? when use cordova activity in Activity parameter.?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I  am try to make one pdf reader plugina in cordova using andorid code at that `NullPointerException` occur in this line    `svScroll.setPDFViewer(this);`
there is diffrent class is there first i m call thia `PDFViewer` class with

```
        PDFViewer m_PDFViewer = new PDFViewer(cordova.getActivity());
```

so can any body help me to solve this issue

```
    public class PDFViewer implements IPassword
    {
        private LinearLayout llPagePane;
        private QScrollView svScroll;

        private float m_CurrentScale;
        private PDFDocument m_Document;
        private float m_FitToWidth;
        private LRUCache m_PageContentsCache;
        private Vector<PDFPageView> m_PageViews;
        private Activity m_ParentActivity;
        private TouchHandlerView m_TouchHandler;

        public PDFViewer(Activity parentActivity)
        {
            m_ParentActivity = parentActivity;

            StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = m_ParentActivity.getAssets();

            llPagePane = (LinearLayout) parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.pagepane);
            svScroll = (QScrollView) parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            svScroll.setPDFViewer(this);

            m_PageContentsCache = new LRUCache(20);
            m_PageViews = new Vector<PDFPageView>();
            m_TouchHandler = new TouchHandlerView(this);
        }
```

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pdfplugin.PDFViewer.<init>(PDFViewer.java:55)
    at com.pdfplugin.pdfreader$1.run(pdfreader.java:69)
```

```
    public void setPDFViewer(PDFViewer viewer)
        {
            m_PDFViewer = viewer;
        }
```

Comment: svScroll.setPDFViewer(this);
 is line 55

Comment: Well then presumably `svScroll` is null, because `findViewById` has returned null...

Comment: m_PDFViewer = new PDFViewer(cordova.getActivity()); is this work or not in java  corodva is phonegap part to provide access activity

Comment: What do you mean by "is this work or not"? The problem is (by the looks of it) that you're trying to find a QScrollView using an ID which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
svScroll = (QScrollView) parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
```

This might be returning `null` that's why

```
 svScroll.setPDFViewer(this);
```

is throwing NullPointerException. Debug and check if its returning null and update you logic accordingly. One possibility that `R.id.scrollview` is not be present. (Dont know much about android.)